# TypeError: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration

Tags: solidity

i need to write a contract with function that returns me the value balance of the wallet increased by 1. can you tell me whats wrong with my code? i am beginner in the solidity.

```
contract balance {
address owner;
uint a = 0;
uint b = 1;
mapping(address => uint) public balanc;
function balancecosh() public {
a = a + b;
return a;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `balancecosh()` function doesn't declare returning any values but then it returns one.

Add `returns (uint)` the function declaration:

```
function balancecosh() public returns (uint) {
    a = a + b;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract balance {
    address owner;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    constructor() public {
        //  If you declare variables - initialize them
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    //  Returns only if called from another function
    function balanceIncrement(address _address) public returns (uint256){
        //  If you initialize owner - check it
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Only owner can increment balances");
        return balances[_address]++;
    }

    //  Returns without modifying chain
    function balanceViewIncrement(address _address) public view returns (uint256 value){
        value = balances[_address];
        value++;
    }
}
```